# how to open a custom layout when menu item is pressed

Tags: android, android-menu

I have created a layout file which needs to displayed when a menu item is pressed.

```
   public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
              ....
       case R.id.help:
           return true;
             ......
    }
}
```

the help item menu should display the layout.xml file.

Comment: Is it an activity or a dialog?

Comment: provide proper discription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the layout in a new `Activity`. You can use `Intent` to invoke this new `Activity`,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or you can write a custom dialog to inflate the layout,

[Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: but can it be launched when the menu item is clicked